# viewing images from django models

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

Im trying to add an image to my polls app, which i have set up as: upload_to='mysite/static/polls_app/question_pics'

but the wrong file path is used when I view the page:
GET /polls/1/static/polls_app/question_pics/

How can I go about editing this so Django uses the url where the image is saved?

Models.py

```
    question_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/polls_app/question_pics', default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Views.py

```
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls_app/detail.html'
```

detail.html

```
<img src="{{ question.question_image.url }}" alt="image">
```

urls.py

```
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below in urls.py

from django.views.static import serve
from django.urls import include,re_path
from . import settings

// Your code as it is

urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^media/(?P.*)', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})]

This should help !!